# Read web content into a dataframe without writing to a file

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read data from the following link to a data frame without saving locally (this is important). I figured out a way (below), but is there an efficient way to do this?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from datetime import datetime


uri = 'https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/request/asos.py?station=AXA&data=all&year1=2022&month1=12&day1=1&year2=2022&month2=12&day2=1&tz=Etc%2FUTC&format=onlycomma&latlon=no&elev=no&missing=M&trace=T&direct=no&report_type=3&report_type=4'
data = urlopen(uri, timeout=300).read().decode("utf-8")

dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')


str1 = data.split('\n')
dfList = []
for ii in range(1,len(str1)):
    if len(str1[ii])>0:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str1[ii]), parse_dates=[1], date_parser=dateparse, header=None) #Read each string into a dataframe
        if not df1.empty:
            df2 = df1.iloc[:,0:3] #Get the first five columns
            if df2.iloc[0,-1] != 'M': #Don't append the ones with missing data
                dfList.append(df2)
df = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = ['Station','Date','Temp']

ax1 = df.plot(x=1,y=2)
ax1.get_figure().autofmt_xdate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) and [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests

url = (
    "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/request/asos.py?"
    "station=AXA&data=all&year1=2022&month1=12&day1=1&year2=2022&"
    "month2=12&day2=1&tz=Etc%2FUTC&format=onlycomma&latlon=no&"
    "elev=no&missing=M&trace=T&direct=no&report_type=3&report_type=4"
)

with requests.Session() as request:
    response = request.get(url, timeout=30)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print(response.raise_for_status())

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), sep=",")
print(df)
```